# Validation is Not working properly in aurelia.js

Tags: aurelia

I am working on a project in which I am using Aurelia for the front end.I am facing an issue for many days but still didn't find any solution I am new in Aurelia and I had tried everything.

[image: front end view]

In this picture you can see there is a required field and a button when we click on this button this should paste the client name in text field everything working fine.

but there is an issue when I am typing anything in the text field and then removing everything and then I click on the button so its saying field is required. 
I understood the problem the problem is my validation is triggering on DOM blur event and when I am changing focus the required validation is triggering.

is there anything I can do?

here is some code snippet.

```
 .ensure('candidatevalidatedby')
    .displayName('Validated by')
    .required()
    .maxLength(60)
```

and

```
<div class="form-group">
<label>Candidate’s ID validated by *</label>
<input class="form-control" value.bind="candidate.candidatevalidatedby & validate" />
</div>
```

Thanks In Advance.

Edit: This issue is fixed.

```
<div class="form-group">
<label>Candidate’s ID validated by *</label>
<input class="form-control" value.bind="candidate.candidatevalidatedby & validateOnChange" />
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried with different validation triggers? By default, it's `blur` but you can change that. Maybe `manual` would work in your case? http://aurelia.io/docs/plugins/validation#validate-binding-behavior

Comment: @MiroslavPopovic Its Working fine now. I had changed blur to change.Thanks

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer so others know this issue is resolved.

Comment: @JeffG I have already posted answer in the question and I will post it in answer section as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution.

```
<div class="form-group">
<label>Candidate’s ID validated by *</label>
<input class="form-control" value.bind="candidate.candidatevalidatedby & 
validateOnChange" />
</div>
```

it's working fine.
http://aurelia.io/docs/plugins/validation#validate-binding-behavior

Answer (score 0):

Add max length attribute to your input element. It will work.